# How to add media gallery entries via REST API - Magento 2

Tags: rest-api, media, gallery, magento2.0.8

I stored image in pub/media/catalog/product. How to add that images into media gallery entries.

I have tried like `http://myhost/rest/V1/products`

```
"media_gallery_entries"=> array(
    array(
        "media_type"=> "image",
        "label"=> "Product Image",
        "position"=> 1,
        "disabled"=> false,
        "types"=> array(
            "image",
            "small_image",
            "thumbnail"
        ),
        "file"=> "/1/0/10.jpg"
    )
),
```

but it always complain about `"message":"The image content is not valid."`

base64_encode is the only way to add image into rest api?

if yes I tried with

```
"media_gallery_entries"=> array(
    array(
        "media_type"=> "image",
        "label"=> "Product Image",
        "position"=> 1,
        "disabled"=> false,
        "types"=> array(
            "image",
            "small_image",
            "thumbnail"
        ),
        "content"=> array(
            "base64_encoded_data"=> $data->getMainImage(),
            "type"=> "image/jpeg",
            "name"=> "test.jpg"
        ),
    )
),
```

It throws exception `"message":"The image MIME type is not valid or not supported."`

I found supported mime type in `/vendor/magento/framework/Api/ImageContentValidator.php`

```
private $defaultMimeTypes = [
    'image/jpg',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/gif',
    'image/png',
];
```

It support `image/jpeg`, but I don't know why it throws exception.

Can anyone enlighten me to how to add media galleries entries?

Comment: oops! it is my fault in second example I encode .png image instead of .jpg. I'm really more concerns about how to add existing image into media gallery entries[First example]. can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with your second example, but instead of `media_type`, use `mediaType` tag.

```
"media_gallery_entries"=> array(
    array(
        "media_type"=> "image",
        "label"=> "Product Image",
        "position"=> 1,
        "disabled"=> false,
        "types"=> array(
            "image",
            "small_image",
            "thumbnail"
        ),
        "content"=> array(
            "base64_encoded_data"=> $data->getMainImage(),
            "type"=> "image/jpeg",
            "name"=> "test.jpg"
        ),
    )
),
```

Also, you'll probably have to use `base64_encode($data->getMainImage())` instead of `$data->getMainImage()` only.

Comment: I tried but no luck, same error `MIME type is not valid or not supported`. I retrive base64 encode string from database `$data->getMainImage()`

Comment: do you have any idea about first example?

Comment: maybe you are retrieving base64 string with "data:image/jpeg;base64," beginning which is not needed. Only `base64_encode()` function output must be passed.

Answer (score 0):

### Notice

1. We should use `image_type_to_mime_type` function to get the MIME type, not use the file extension, because  extension sometime is wrong.
2. `'data:image/'.$type.';base64,'` beginning in the base64 string **doesn't need in Magento2**, we just need `base64_encode($imageData);`

### Work Example: post product image from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.2

```
<?php
$imagePath = $product->getImage();
$imageFullPath = Mage::getBaseDir('media').'/catalog/product'.$imagePath;
$imageName = basename($imagePath);
$imageType = exif_imagetype($imageFullPath);
$mimeType = image_type_to_mime_type($imageType);
$imageData = file_get_contents($imageFullPath);
$base64EncodedData = base64_encode($imageData);

$json =
    '{
      "product": {
        ...
        "media_gallery_entries": [{
            "media_type": "image",
            "label": "'.$imageName.'",
            "position": 0,
            "disabled": false,
            "types": [
                "image",
                "small_image",
                "thumbnail"
            ],
            "file": "'.$imagePath.'",
            "content": {
                "base64_encoded_data": "'.$base64EncodedData.'",
                "type": "'.$mimeType.'",
                "name": "'.$imageName.'"
            }
        }],
        ...
      }
    }'
```